# How to Connect controller rendering with Interface Template

Tags: helix, controller

I am trying to create a simple Image controller Rendering and I don't want to add the template interface to my page type, because I want to add the image dynamicaly to my site.

So here my "problems" begin.

I've created a simple Controllerrendering with a viewmodel

```
public class PageImageViewModel
{
    public HtmlString PageImage { get; set; }
}
```

as simple Controller call to my ModelBuilder

```
public ActionResult PageImage()
{
    return View(PageImageModelBuilder.GetPageImageViewModel(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item));
}
```

and the modelbuilder

```
public PageImageViewModel GetPageImageViewModel(Item currentItem)
{
    var model = new PageImageViewModel();
    model.PageImage = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(currentItem, Templates.PageImage.Fields.Image_FieldName));
    return model;
}
```

and the view

```
@using Bazar.Feature.PageContent
@model Bazar.Feature.PageContent.Models.Models.PageImageViewModel

<div class="">
    <p>Hallo Welt</p>
     @Model.PageImage
</div>
```

thats the codeside I think that should work.

and now the sitecore elments

- I've created a Interface Template for my _PageImage
- I've created the Controller rendering

[image]

[image]

- And I've tried to add this new control to my "Home" view where I've some dynamic placeholders but I don't get the modal where I can choose what Image I want to see.
- try to add the controller rendering to my page

[image]

- but after that no image selection is opened and the final layout looks like

[image]

- and I can't edit or select the Image
  [image]
- so far I understand my Problem is the controller rendering has no connection to my Interface Template _PageImage but I don't understand how to get this "connection"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The fix

You need to specify a template in the `Datasource Template` field of your controller rendering. This is the field that tells Sitecore to prompt an editor to select a data source when adding a rendering.

[image: Image of Datasource Location and Datasource Template fields]

#### A cool feature

Sitecore will take template inheritance into account when allowing you to select data sources, which means that you'll be able to select any item that has a base template of the one you select here (e.g. `_PageImage`).

#### Another recommendation

Additionally, it's good practice to specify the location under which data sources can be found by putting that path in the `Datasource Location` field:

[image]

Comment: When this is the simple fix, what would be the right approach or is there no right or wrong

Comment: This is the right approach. Sorry if my wording was unclear. I'll remove the "simple."